# Word for "a person looking for a match"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, computing

I'm writing up some code and I'm having some trouble naming my variables. You say, "I'm looking for a match." So your supposed partner who has similar attributes is your "*match*". Then what are *you* called?

Comment: Why can't you be their match? It's reciprocal, isn't it? Unlike mentor and mentee, matches are equal.

Comment: You're right. But i'm actually using this as a variable name in a code I'm writing up. I could use match1 and match2, but I'm not really a fan of names that don't define themselves (when you say match1 and match2 does it mean there are 2 matches for you?) So it doesn't really fit into my context. So I'm looking for a word to pair up with my variable named *match* which is the supposed match for "me". So what am *I* called?

Comment: Think of it like Tinder. So you're looking for your *match*. Should you be called "finder"? I'm not sure if it fits the description well.

Comment: I don't think there is such a word. You might have come up with a coined combination. Like `matchSource` and `matchTarget`

Comment: Oh alright. I'll go with that for now as they somehow give sense to it. Thanks!

Comment: Challenger? While the challenger is in the queue the match is found. Maybe they can be matched to the opponent?

Comment: It wasn't really what I'm looking for, but yes that could work! Noted!

Comment: How about "lightless"?  Or "unlit"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our Help Center specifically states that picking names for things in programming is beyond our remit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single words "**seeker**" or "**searcher**" seem most fitting given your example. They can be combined with several other words like "query", "questions", "profile", or "template" if a more descriptive term/phrase is needed or desireable.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/searcher

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/seeker